# Problems with creating Database with PHP

Tags: php, validation, syntax-error

I am having issues with my PHP code creating a database in EasyPHP

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
if($conn)
    echo "<p>Connection set up successfully.</p>";
mysqli_query($conn, "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS hotelDB");
if (mysqli_query($conn, "CREATE DATABASE hotelDB"))
    echo "<p>Database created successfully.</p>";
mysqli_select_db($conn, "hotelDB");
//room_type table
$myStatement= "CREATE TABLE room_type
(
room_type_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
room_type_name VARCHAR(100),
total_room INT DEFAULT 5,
CONSTRAINT pk_room_type PRIMARY KEY (room_type_id)
);";
//reservation table
$myStatement .="CREATE TABLE reservation
(
reservation_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
room_type_id INT NOT NULL
begin_date DATE NOT NULL
end_date DATE NOT NULL
confirm_number CHAR(13),
CONSTRAINT pk_reservation PRIMARY KEY (reservation_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_reservation_room_type FOREIGN KEY (room_type_id) REFERENCES
room_type (room_type_id)
);";
if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $myStatement))
    echo "<p>Table created successfully.</p>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I am still relatively new with PHP. I ran it through a PHP validation and it said there where no syntax issues. I don't know where to start.

Comment: Kindly accept my answer if it helps you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using "**root**" user with no password to connect to Database. 
You need to set password or better to create a new db user.
By default remote connections with root aren`t allowed so you need to GRAND remote access.

Comment: What if someone set empty password in database installation?

Answer (score 0):

There was some error in your sql query. You were missing `commas` in your second query which I have also described in comments also. Always use this `mysqli_error($conn)` for detecting errors.
  Try this code

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
if($conn)
    echo "<p>Connection set up successfully.</p>";
mysqli_query($conn, "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS hotelDB");
if (mysqli_query($conn, "CREATE DATABASE hotelDB"))
    echo "<p>Database created successfully.</p>";
mysqli_select_db($conn, "hotelDB");
//room_type table


$myStatement1= "CREATE TABLE room_type
    (
    room_type_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    room_type_name VARCHAR(100),
    total_room INT DEFAULT 5,
    CONSTRAINT pk_room_type PRIMARY KEY (room_type_id)
    );";
//I have ran each query separately
if (mysqli_query($conn, $myStatement1))
    echo "<p>Table created successfully.</p>";

else

    echo mysqli_error($conn);//for detecting error in the last query if any
//reservation table
$myStatement2 ="CREATE TABLE reservation
    (
    reservation_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    room_type_id INT NOT NULL, 
    begin_date DATE NOT NULL, 
    end_date DATE NOT NULL,  
    confirm_number CHAR(13),
    CONSTRAINT pk_reservation PRIMARY KEY (reservation_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_reservation_room_type FOREIGN KEY (room_type_id) REFERENCES
    room_type (room_type_id)
    );";//You were missing commas in this query.
if (mysqli_query($conn, $myStatement2))
    echo "<p>Table created successfully.</p>";
else

    echo mysqli_error($conn);//for detecting error in the last query if any
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

It works perfectly